# SWT TrayItem Mouse listener

Tags: java, swt, system-tray

I use SWT for my app and all significance of it, to use system tray. May be some one know how to add mouse listener to the TrayItem (or just handle mouse events)? For example, handle mouse hover event.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT TrayItems seems not to implement mouselisteners.
However: If you just need to show a tooltip on mouse hover, use [`public void setToolTipText(String string)`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TrayItem.html#setToolTipText(java.lang.String)) method of `TrayItem` class.